# Find all roots in R[x] of $f(x) = x^2 −2x$ when R = Z/30Z

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, modular-arithmetic

So I'm thinking that for this to be true, we need

x^2-2x = 0 (mod 5) and x^2-2x = 0 (mod 2) and  x^2-2x = 0 (mod 3)

Then, 
x = 0 (mod 5) or x = 2 (mod 5)
x = 0 (mod 2) or x = 2 (mod 2)
x = 0 (mod 3) or x = 2 (mod 3)

Is this the right approach? Is this how I would represent the roots ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, whoever posed this question intended for you to give the roots modulo 30.

To do this, use the Chinese Remainder Theorem on what you have so far.  You should get four distinct roots.

Note that, in solving modulo 2, you have written the same root twice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the equation as $\;(x-1)^2=1$. Thus you have to find the square roots of $1$ modulo $30$. By the Chinese Remainder theorem, this amounts to finding the square roots of $1$ in $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, in $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$ and in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$. In a field with characteristic $\ne 2$, it has $2$ square roots, hence you'll obtain $4$ square roots in all.

Comment: Do al fields with characteristic = 2 not have any square roots? Also I came up with 1 and 2 as roots in mod 3 and 1 and 4 as roots in mod 5. Do I have to convert them to mod 30? In that case wouldn't tehre be an overlap since 1 is a root twice ?

Comment: It can , but a square root will be a double root, since $-1=1$ in characteristic $2$.